# Removing a - from a column in data frame and replacing with a 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some football data from an excel file and in some columns there is a - symbol that I would like to change to a zero.

```
34   The New Saints       Cardiff MU    14       4.07       43              
35      Fredrikstad            Skeid    14       4.07       43      
36             Hodd         Brattvag    14       4.07       43      
37              JJK       Vaajakoski     -          -        -                      
38         Partizan  CSKA 1948 Sofia     -          -        -       

39     Stromsgodset        Mjondalen    14       4.07       43      
40          Orgryte        KFUM Oslo     -          -        -       
41         Belshina    Dnepr Mogilev     -          -        -       
42         Strommen      Kvik Halden     -          -        -       
43     IFK Goteborg     Sarpsborg0 8    14      4.07        43              
44           Baerum            Asker    14       4.07       43
```

I have tried the following

```
df.loc[df['H_GS+GCPM '] == '-', 'H_GS+GCPM '] = 0
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

`df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)`